# How to generate the "left-comments, right-code" site looks like backbone source demo?

Tags: backbone.js, demo

Backbone has a great source demo: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html

The left side is the comments, and right is code. Is there any tool to generate such a site or pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tool is called [docco](http://jashkenas.github.com/docco/), by the main author of Backbone itself ;)
It's a pretty minimal coffe script relying on markdown and pygments to do the job and there is a multitude of clones in other languages that do exactly the same thing if you don't like running node to generate documentation. You will find them in the same page.